# Convert Oracle Recursive Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-migration, sql-server-2016, recursive-query

I develop SQL for OracleDB and I thought about switching to SQL Server for a couple of reasons.

Well to make it short I want to convert a query but I can't get my head around it :/ Maybe you guys could help me.

```
SELECT A.Field1, A.Field2
FROM (SELECT Field1, Field2
             FROM Table1
             WHERE Field3 = 1) A
WHERE A.Field2 = 2
CONNECT BY A.Field2 = PRIOR A.Field1
```

Comment: In SQL Server you would use a Recursive CTE for this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Could u provide some sample data and expected output as `formatted` text?

Comment: Yes I already got that with the CTEs but I don't understand how to write my statement as a CTE